# Is there any way to check whether a file exist with a file name contains regular expression

Tags: c++, path, file-exists

Given the path you are search under, and the file name contains regular expression, is there any way to check whether there is any file satisfy the file name pattern exists under this path? In C++?? for example:
under path

```
/path
```

I want to search the file "foo.*"

```
foo.*
```

the result could be foo.1 or foo.2 or whatever. I would like to get the result(I mean I want to know whether the file exist and the exact file name), Thanks

Comment: The search term you are looking for is ["glob"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). On Linux-y systems, see [`glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html). On Windows, `FindFirstFile` et al.

Comment: do you mean foo followed by anything (a regex) or foo followed by a dot followed by anything (a glob)?

Comment: Bear in mind the answer to any such question is out of date as soon as you get it - what if a new file is created?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, "glob" seems something I am searching for

Answer (score 0):

Look into [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), otherwise you will need to look at the api for your os.

Here is an example (untested):

```
boost::filesystem::path dir("/path");
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(dir), end;
BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::filesystem::path& p, std::make_pair(it, end))
{
    if(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p))
    {
        if(p.stem().string() == "foo")
        {
            std::cout << p.extension() << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```